# How do I find my process is CPU/Memory or Disk intensive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to scale up my ec2 instances and I have to choose whether my processes need more CPU/Memory or EBS stores.

How do I find out?

Answer (score 0):

SSH to the command line and use the top command.  It will give you a list of processes and their processor/memory usage.  You will see if you are over or under utilizing your memory and processor.

```
$ top
```